# Specify Samba account when connecting from Windows to OS X

Tags: windows, macos, smb

I am trying to connect to a shared directory on my Macbook which is shared using SMB. This directory is only shared on 1 account, so it is not publicly available.

When I try to connect to this share from my Windows PC I only see an empty folder and it is not asking me any credentials.

How can I force Windows to connect to the smb using specific account credentials?

Answer (score 0):

```
net use \\server\share /user:Shared_account /savecred
```

Remember that credentials are per-server, not per-share, so *all* shares under `\\server` will now use the given credentials.